# ASP.NET Stack Trace Question

Tags: asp.net

This is something that I have been curious about for a bit, but have never found the solution to:

After I publish an application to a server, if it throws an error, the Stack Trace still contains references to my local environment.  E.G.:

> at [appname].dropdown.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\Desktop\[solution]\[project]\dropdown.cs:line 74

Why does it refer to my local paths instead of the servers paths of these objects?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sending debug versions/*.pdb files to the server?

Answer (score 1):

As the debug information contains the file name at the moment that it was compiled. It's just a text value, it's not updated with the path of the actual file.

The actual name of the file wouldn't be very useful anyway, as that would be some generated file name somewhere in the .NET cache folder.

Comment: Is there a way to remove this reference? I have tried to compile with the 'Release' configuration, and I have set the debug value in the web.config file to false. I then compile and publish, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you published a compiled version built on your machine.